# RSpec "should be_valid" is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm writing a model test in RSpec and this is the code I have:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe User do
before do
  @user = User.new(name: "Ryan", email: "email@email.com", password: "ryan", password_confirmation: "ryan")
end

subject { @user }

describe "Basic model properties" do
  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }
  #it { should be_valid }
end

describe "when name is not present" do
  before { @user.name = "" }
  it { should_not be_valid }
end
```

However when I run it using `bundle exec rspec spec/`, I get an error saying "undefined method [] for nil:NilClass on the line where it says `it { should_not be valid }`. If I comment out that line then the test passes.

Why am I getting this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
describe "when name is not present" do
  before { @user.name = "" }
  it { should_not be_valid }
end
```

To

```
describe "when name is not present" do
  before { subject.name = "" }
  it { should_not be_valid }
end
```

See rspec docs for more info
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/subject/explicit-subject#access-subject-from-before-block

Also you may want to look at shoulda-matchers (https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) and then you wouldn't need to bother with doing anything special in the before block

```
describe "Basic model properties" do
  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
end
```